# Linux command output not getting redirected

Tags: linux, bash

Why doesn't the output get redirected in this case. The user doesn't have permission to write in /proc hence the error but why the error isn't going to /dev/null?

```
$echo "core_%e.%p" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern 2>&1 > /dev/null

-bash: /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern: Permission denied
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23964/why-is-redirecting-stderr-to-dev-null-done-this-way/23966#23966

Comment: None of these work either.$echo "core_%e.%p" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern 2>&1 1> /dev/null
$ echo "core_%e.%p" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern 1> /dev/null 2>&1
$ echo "core_%e.%p" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern > /dev/null 2>&1

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
echo "core_%e.%p" 2>/dev/null > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern 2>&1
```

that will send stdout and stderr to "core_pattern", if possible, if not, ends without message.

Answer (score 0):

works too:

`bash -c 'echo "core_%e.%p" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern' > /dev/null 2>&1`